# ListFragment tabs program compiles without any errors but refuses to install

Tags: java, android, xml

i'm a newbie to android programming.So please pardon me if i'm asking senseless questions.After following a couple of tutorials on how to create ListFragments,the program written compiles with no errors,but refuses to install on AVD.
Here is the error it gives

```
[2014-05-08 07:44:46 - TabsWithSwipe] Uploading TabsWithSwipe.apk onto device 'emulator-      5554'
[2014-05-08 07:44:46 - TabsWithSwipe] Installing TabsWithSwipe.apk...
[2014-05-08 07:48:59 - TabsWithSwipe] Failed to install TabsWithSwipe.apk on device 'emulator-5554!
[2014-05-08 07:48:59 - TabsWithSwipe] (null)
[2014-05-08 07:49:00 - TabsWithSwipe] Launch canceled!
```

Here are the individual codes if it would help elaborate the problem.
    MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.tabswithswipe;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

import com.example.tabswithswipe.adapter.TabsPagerAdapter;



@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity  implements ActionBar.TabListener{
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
    private ActionBar actionBar;
    //tab titles

    private String[] tabs = {"Top Rated","Games","Movies"};


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
        actionBar = getActionBar();
        mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        //ADding TAbs
        for (String tab_name : tabs)
        {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                         .setTabListener(this));
    }
    //on swipping the viewpager make respective tab selected
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            public void onPageSelected(int position)
            {
                //on changing the page
                //make respected tab selected
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2)
            {

            }
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0)
            {

            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager 
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here's the class of TabsPagerAdapter

```
package com.example.tabswithswipe.adapter;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;

import com.example.tabswithswipe.GamesFragment;
import com.example.tabswithswipe.MoviesFragment;
import com.example.tabswithswipe.TopRatedFragment;


public class TabsPagerAdapter  extends FragmentPagerAdapter{
    public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm){
        super(fm);
    }
    public ListFragment getItem(int index) 
    {
        switch(index)
        {
        case 0:
            //Top Rated fragment activity
            return new TopRatedFragment();

        case 1:
            //Games fragment activity
            return new GamesFragment();

        case 2:
            //Movies fragment activity
            return new MoviesFragment();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public int getCount()
    {
        //get item count,equal to number of tabs
        return 3;
    }


}
```

Here is one of the custom ListFragments called GameFragments

```
package com.example.tabswithswipe;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class GamesFragment extends ListFragment {
    String[] list_items;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_games, container, false);
        list_items = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.my_data_list);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list_items));

        return rootView;
    }



}
```

Here is the xml for this gameFragment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ff8400"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"

        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent ="true"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The Other two customs listFragment classes and xml's are thesame.
I will appreciate any help out there

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your emulator doesn't support the APIs you use, because the Android-version on your emulator is too low.

Try using an emulator with an android version > 4.0

Comment: Here are the specifications of the emulator i'm using Name:Nexus
CPU/ABI:ARM(armeabi-v7a)

Target:Android 4.2.2(API LEVEL 17)

Skin:720xx1280